# How to write subquery inside the OUTER JOIN Statement

Tags: sql

I want to join two table CUSTMR and DEPRMNT.

My needed is: LEFT OUTER JOIN OF two or more Tables with subquery inside the LEFT OUTER JOIN as shown below:

Table: CUSTMR , DEPRMNT

Query as:

```
SELECT
    cs.CUSID
    ,dp.DEPID
FROM
    CUSTMR cs
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT
                    dp.DEPID
                    ,dp.DEPNAME
                FROM
                    DEPRMNT dp
                WHERE
                    dp.DEPADDRESS = 'TOKYO'
        )
            ON (
                dp.DEPID = cs.CUSID
                AND cs.CUSTNAME = dp.DEPNAME
            )
WHERE
    cs.CUSID != ''
```

Here the subquery is:

```
SELECT
    dp.DEPID, dp.DEPNAME
FROM
    DEPRMNT dp
WHERE
    dp.DEPADDRESS = 'TOKYO'
```

Is it possible to write such subquery inside LEFT OUTER JOIN?

I am getting an error when running this query on my DB2 database.

Comment: You should always post the errormessage you receive.

Comment: Why does the title say INNER JOIN and the question say OUTER JOIN??... I'm editing this

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You need the "correlation id" (the "AS SS" thingy)  on the sub-select to reference the fields in the "ON" condition. The id's assigned inside the sub select are not usable in the join.

```
SELECT
       cs.CUSID
       ,dp.DEPID
FROM
    CUSTMR cs
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT
                    DEPID
                    ,DEPNAME
                FROM
                    DEPRMNT 
                WHERE
                    dp.DEPADDRESS = 'TOKYO'
        ) ss
            ON (
                ss.DEPID = cs.CUSID
                AND ss.DEPNAME = cs.CUSTNAME
            )
WHERE
    cs.CUSID != ''
```

Comment: Yes! "James Anderson", Thanks you so much. My problem was solved. I found My problem was due to the alias name. **Inner Sub query should always have a alias name!**

Comment: Is this a correlated sub-query, and thus ends up being bad performance?

Comment: "Performance" depends entirely on available indexes, available memory, physiccal dsik allocation, cardinality, how much money you paid for the software, etc. etc.. Having the syntactically correct SQL is only a starting point.

Comment: Performance DOES NOT depend on how much you paid for the software.  Classic correlation => causation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to use sub query in this scenario.You can directly left outer join the DEPRMNT  table .

While using Left Outer Join ,don't use columns in the RHS table of the join in the where condition, you ll get wrong output

Comment: .Actually in my business logic, sub-query have group by used, at that time we required to write sub query!