# Getting duplicates values and summing up of 2nd column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Test and it`s data is :

```
    A   B
    1   One
    2   One
    2   Two
    3   One
    2   One
    5   Two
    2   Three
    2   Two
    2   Three
    2   Two
    2   One
```

Now i want the output like following :

```
    A   B
    10  One
    10  One
    11  Two
    10  One
    10  One
    11  Two
    4   Three
    11  Two
    4   Three
    11  Two
    10  One
```

I tried

SELECT B,SUM(A) FROM Test GROUP BY A but i got :

```
One    10
Three   4
Two    11
```

Can anybody tell me how we can acheive the same in shortest way, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(A) OVER (PARTITION BY B), B FROM Test
```

Comment: Better answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.B, t2.sum_a
FROM Test t1
  join (select b, sum(a) as sum_a from test group by b) t2 on t1.b = t2.b
```

Comment: Nenad Zivkovic's answer is better as long as the dbms supports that syntax. (If not, use my answer instead.)

Comment: @jarlh True, but the question was tagged as sql-server. It will not work in most other DBMS-es

Comment: yeah, i need it for sql-server only, thanks both of you guys for giving your time.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to make a subselect, where perfom the sum and group by B column, then join this subselect with your current table.

```
SELECT original.B, subquery.total 
FROM original 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT B, SUM(A) AS total FROM original GROUP BY B) as subselect ON original.B = subquery.B
```

Check this other stackoverflow: [How to write subquery inside the OUTER JOIN Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493512/how-to-write-subquery-inside-the-inner-join-statement?answertab=votes#tab-top)